# jsPDF text over same position

Tags: jspdf

I'm using jsPDF. At first time the report is generated some texts keep the letters in same postions like this:

[image]

After close the report and rebuild in second time is generated correctly, and the error not ocourr again.

[image]

Anybody can help-me?
tks

Comment: Maybe you could post some of your code or a repository link?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your code logic. Maybe you're trying to generate the pdf the first time with null/blank variables. Could you post a piece of your code?

Comment: answering this without code is impossible.

Comment: this is a typical [Crystal ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_ball) question